# Adding new item to Object useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I need help, I have problem to add a new items to my Object useState,
I want to add items array of object a new item, can some one help me?

my useState :

```
const [kolom, setKolom] = useState({
    ["Main-Todo"]: {
      columnName: "Todo",
      items: [
        {
          id: v4(),
          content: "Makan ayam di MCD ",
        },
        {
          id: v4(),
          content: "Main bola sama presiden Putin ⚽",
        },
      ],
    },
    [v4()]: {
      columnName: "In-Progress",
      items: [],
    },
  });
```

here's my code try to add items array of object in useState :

```
 setKolom({
         ...kolom,
          ["Main-Todo"]: {
            items: addTask,
          },
        });
      }}
```

Thanks a lot, i new at react js

Comment: I would recommend using immerjs

Comment: Are you wanting to replace the `items` array with `addTask` or add to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) form to update the existing value and merge your change in with the current `Main-Todo` object

```js
setKolom((prev) => ({ 
  ...prev,                // current kolom
  "Main-Todo": {
    ...prev["Main-Todo"], // current kolom["Main-Todo"]
    items: addTask,       // new items
  },
}));
```

---

If by *"add items array"* you mean you want to append to the existing array as opposed to replacing it, you need only change one line...

```js
items: prev["Main-Todo"].items.concat(addTask)
```

Using `Array.prototype.concat()` works if `addTask` is an array or a single object.

Comment: items should contains previous items of prev["Main-Todo"].items so
`items: [...prev["Main-Todo"].items, addTask]`

Comment: @AhmedLazhar it's not entirely clear from OP's question but I've [asked for clarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73232818/adding-new-item-to-object-usestate/73232868#comment129335147_73232818)

Answer (score 1):

If you can use immerjs it can be written this way:

```js
      setKolom(produce(draft => {
         draft["Main-Todo"].items.push(addedTask),
      }))
```

Comment: Looks like OP wants to replace `items`, not append. But I could be wrong

Comment: the OP said: I want to add items array of object a new item